# How to analyze a data frame and get another with values greater than 0.05?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with different values of p.value includind missing values (NA):
pvalue2=pvalue[1:679,3:10]
and I need to analyze it and the numbers greater than 0.05 i need to write "Normal" e values less than 0.05 i need to write the value. I want the result to be written in another data frame.
This is my code:

```
a=data.frame()
    for (i in 1:nrow(pvalue2)) {
      for (j in 1:ncol(pvalue2)){
        if (pvalue2[i,j] >=0.05) {
          print (a[i,j]=="Normal")
        } else {print a[i,j]==pvalue2[i,j] }
      }
    }
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- ifelse(as.matrix(pvalue2) < .05, as.matrix(pvalue2), "normal")
a <- as.data.frame(a)
```

Since R is a high level language that is not compiled, `for` loops have a tendendency to get *very* slow when they grow. By using vectorized functions instead (that do the looping in a lower level language internally) you speed up the code and make it more readable.

#### Example run

```
> set.seed(123)
> pvalue2 <- matrix(runif(18)/10, 6, 3)
> pvalue2[sample(length(pvalue2), 4)] <- NA
> pvalue2 <- as.data.frame(pvalue2)
> pvalue2

          V1         V2          V3
1 0.02875775 0.05281055 0.067757064
2 0.07883051 0.08924190 0.057263340
3 0.04089769 0.05514350          NA
4 0.08830174 0.04566147 0.089982497
5 0.09404673         NA          NA
6         NA 0.04533342 0.004205953

> ifelse(as.matrix(pvalue2) < .05, as.matrix(pvalue2), "normal")

     V1                   V2                   V3                   
[1,] "0.0287577520124614" "normal"             "normal"             
[2,] "normal"             "normal"             "normal"             
[3,] "0.04089769218117"   "normal"             NA                   
[4,] "normal"             "0.0456614735303447" "normal"             
[5,] "normal"             NA                   NA                   
[6,] NA                   "0.0453334156190977" "0.00420595335308462"
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working. I really don´t know why. I have the data frame with all values ou all "normal".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, your p values are stored as factors. You need to convert them to numeric values first.

```
tmp <- sapply(pvalue2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Now, the object `tmp` can be used:

```
# copy the existing data frame to a new object
df2 <- pvalue2
# fill it with "Normal"
df2[ , ] <- "Normal"
# replace with values from tmp if value < 0.05
df2[tmp < 0.05] <- pvalue2[tmp < 0.05]
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this solution I just have a data frame with missing values.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your first data frame is called df

```
df_2<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=nrow(df),ncol=ncol(df)));
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    df_2[,i]<-ifelse(is.na(df[,i]) == FALSE && df[,i] >= .05,"Normal",ifelse(is.na(df[,i])==FALSE && df[,i] < 0.05,df[,i],NA))
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `df_2 <- ...` inside the `for`?

Comment: @Rcoster why ? df_2 is the frame to which the output will go, df is the frame which contains the pvalues

Comment: When i used this code I have this warnings

Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(df[, i], 0.05) : >= not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(df[, i], 0.05) : >= not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(df[, i], 0.05) : >= not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(df[, i], 0.05) : >= not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(df[, i], 0.05) : >= not meaningful for factors
6: In Ops.factor(df[, i], 0.05) : >= not meaningful for factors
7: In Ops.factor(df[, i], 0.05) : >= not meaningful for factors

And besides the result is a data frame with missing values.

Comment: cast occurrences of df[,i] to as.numeric(df[,i])

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(a=runif(10,0,0.1),b=runif(10,0,0.1))
#since there are only numeric values
#you can transform to matrix
m <- as.matrix(df)

#new matrix
m2 <- m

m2[m>0.05] <- "Normal"

df2 <- as.data.frame(m2)

                    a                  b
1              Normal  0.045774177624844
2              Normal             Normal
3  0.0286139534786344             Normal
4              Normal 0.0255428824340925
5              Normal 0.0462292822543532
6              Normal             Normal
7              Normal             Normal
8   0.013466659723781 0.0117487361654639
9              Normal 0.0474997081561014
10             Normal             Normal
```

Comment: I don´t understand what happening with my r. The data frame in your solution work, in my don´t.